# Pattern matching on enum type in Java 22

Tags: java, java-22

I have a java enum:

```java
public enum PaxosRole {
    FOLLOWER,
    RECOVERER,
    LEADER
}
```

I wish to use it in a record such as:

```java
public record PaxosEvent(PaxosRole role, PaxosMessage message) {}
```

When I try to pattern match it with:

```java
        final var paxosEvent = new PaxosEvent(role, msg);
        switch (paxosEvent){
            case PaxosEvent(PaxosRole.FOLLOWER, var msg) -> {
                // do something
            }
            case PaxosEvent(PaxosRole.RECOVERER, var msg) -> {
                // do something else
            }
            case PaxosEvent(PaxosRole.LEADER, var msg) -> {
                // do something distinct
            }

        }
```

My IDE says `Unknown class` for the enum in the pattern matches.

Trying to swap the enum for a complex sealed class:

```java
sealed interface PaxosRole {
    record Follower() implements PaxosRole {};
    record Recoverer() implements PaxosRole {};
    record Leader() implements PaxosRole {};

    Follower FOLLOWER = new Follower();
    Recoverer RECOVERER = new Recoverer();
    Leader LEADER = new Leader();
}
```

Then the following does not work:

```java
        switch (paxosEvent){
            case PaxosEvent(PaxosRole.Follower _, var msg) -> {
                throw new AssertionError("follower role not implemented");
            }
            case PaxosEvent(PaxosRole.Recoverer _, var msg) -> {
                throw new AssertionError("follower role not implemented");
            }
            case PaxosEvent(PaxosRole.Leader _, var msg) -> {
                throw new AssertionError("follower role not implemented");
            }

        }
```

My IDE says that only the first branch will match; the other two branches are the same class. I am guessing it thinks all are of type `PaxosRole`. Even if it was to work, it looks pretty verbose.

I can use a `with` to check the enum:

```java
        switch (paxosEvent){
            case PaxosEvent(var role, var m) when role.equals(PaxosRole.FOLLOWER)-> {
                throw new AssertionError("follower role not implemented");
            }
            case PaxosEvent(var role, var m) when role.equals(PaxosRole.RECOVERER)-> {
                throw new AssertionError("follower role not implemented");
            }
            case PaxosEvent(var role, var m) when role.equals(PaxosRole.LEADER)-> {
                throw new AssertionError("follower role not implemented");
            }
        }
```

Yet my IDE then tells me that the match is not exhaustive. So, it wants me to add a default branch. Yet it is exhaustive; all three enums are covered in the `with` statements.

Is there a way to use a simple enum in a switch in Java 22 without a default and without being so verbose?

Comment: Why do you want to wrap it in a class again, just switch on PaxosRole?

Comment: Record patterns don't allow using enum constants inside as they only permit type (local variable declarations) and record patterns. However, as @GijsDenHollander mentioned, you can just `switch` over `paxosEvent.role`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `when` in every `case` checking the enum but the last one. This will be exhaustive (you don't need a `default`) but it won't check exhaustiveness ob the enum's values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mixing value cases and record/type patterns is not supported yet.

Your work-around

```java
sealed interface PaxosRole {
    record Follower() implements PaxosRole {};
    record Recoverer() implements PaxosRole {};
    record Leader() implements PaxosRole {};

    Follower FOLLOWER = new Follower();
    Recoverer RECOVERER = new Recoverer();
    Leader LEADER = new Leader();
}
```

```java
switch(paxosEvent){
    case PaxosEvent(PaxosRole.Follower _, var msg) -> {
        throw new AssertionError("follower role not implemented");
    }
    case PaxosEvent(PaxosRole.Recoverer _, var msg) -> {
        throw new AssertionError("recoverer role not implemented");
    }
    case PaxosEvent(PaxosRole.Leader _, var msg) -> {
        throw new AssertionError("leader role not implemented");
    }
}
```

does work with `javac`; any problems in your IDE are related to the IDE.

Alternatively, you can use record patterns instead of type patterns:

```java
switch(paxosEvent) {
    case PaxosEvent(PaxosRole.Follower(), var msg) -> {
        throw new AssertionError("follower role not implemented");
    }
    case PaxosEvent(PaxosRole.Recoverer(), var msg) -> {
        throw new AssertionError("recoverer role not implemented");
    }
    case PaxosEvent(PaxosRole.Leader(), var msg) -> {
        throw new AssertionError("leader role not implemented");
    }
}
```

---

But there is no need for pattern matching at all with your original definition of `PaxosRole` as an `enum` type. You could simply use

```java
switch(paxosEvent.role()) {
    case FOLLOWER -> {
        throw new AssertionError("follower role not implemented");
    }
    case RECOVERER -> {
        throw new AssertionError("recoverer role not implemented");
    }
    case LEADER -> {
        throw new AssertionError("leader role not implemented");
    }
}
```

This would require accessing `paxosEvent.message()` manually when needed. If you really need to avoid that, you can nest switch statements:

```java
switch(paxosEvent) {
    case PaxosEvent(var role, var msg) -> {
        switch(role) {
            case FOLLOWER -> {
                throw new AssertionError("follower role not implemented");
            }
            case RECOVERER -> {
                throw new AssertionError("recoverer role not implemented");
            }
            case LEADER -> {
                throw new AssertionError("leader role not implemented");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This can still be quite compact. E.g. as an expression:

```java
int i = switch(paxosEvent) {
    case PaxosEvent(var role, var msg) -> switch(role) {
        case FOLLOWER -> 1;
        case RECOVERER -> 2;
        case LEADER -> 3;
    };
};
```

And pattern matching will evolve. Patterns like in your first attempt might be possible in the future…